# How can I put a transparent colored sheet over the image?

Tags: html, css, image, opacity, rgba

There is an image that looks like :

[image]

and there is copy of this image that looks like :

[image]

How can I put a transparent-blue sheet over the image ? I tried this :

```
<img src="bg2.jpg" style="background-color:rgba(34,70,118,0.7);" />
```

but it didn't work. How can I do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess like this

```
<div class="image-holder">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/vqpYb.jpg">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
</div>

.image-holder {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}
.overlay { 
    background-color:rgba(34,70,118,0.7);
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/84L1cvmw/

Comment: Can you please explain what does `position = relative` and `float = left` do here w.r.t `overlay` ?

Comment: @SuhailGupta `float: left;` make div same width as image, `position: relative` used to determine starting position for children elements

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way:

- Background on `div.image-holder`.
- Reduced opacity on the `<img>`.
- `display: block` on the `<img>` to remove the gap (The default display for `<img>` is `display: inline-block`).

You can also easily transition on hover and increase the opacity to normal.

[Have an example!](http://jsbin.com/vemim/1/edit)

HTML

```
<div class="image-holder">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/vqpYb.jpg" />
</div>
```

CSS

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.image-holder {
    background: blue;
    float: left;
}
.image-holder img {
    opacity: 0.5;
    display: block;
    transition: opacity 0.6s;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.image-holder img:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
```